# Axios: Not going into catch method with error

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

I have a function to edit a contract name. I call an axios request to the backend API with the specific ID. For each case I call a sweetalert message.

```
axios({
       url: '/api/contract/' + id,
       method: 'put',
       data: {
             name: name
       }
       }) .then((response) => {
          this.$emit('fetchAll');
          swal({
               title: "Success!",
               icon: "success"
          });
       }) .catch(error => {
          this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
          swal({
             title: "Error",
             text: error.response.data.message,
             icon: "error"
       });
});
```

With response:

```
403: You are not authorized to edit this contract.
```

[image: network console]

Error handling in Laravel controller:

```
if (Bouncer::cannot('contract-destroy'))
    abort('403', "You are not authorized to delete this contract");
```

Even when there is an error from the request, the success message pops up.

Comment: how you are returning the errors from Larave?

Comment: Look in your browser's _Network_ console. What is the status of the response there?

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz I use the abort function: abort(403, "You are not authorized to edit this organisation");

Comment: @Phil The response is 403: You are not authorized to edit this contract.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot from the console?

Comment: try `return response('message', 403 );`

Comment: @Phil https://puu.sh/BBQZV/86015cd133.png

Comment: So.. is the then callback being run?  Everything looks fine here, my guess is you are hitting some error in your callback.

Comment: @Devon if there is an error thrown within a promises' resolve callback, it throws the exception and fires the reject (catch) callback.

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz exactly the same happens, still going to the 'then' callback

Comment: I just tried it with a delete and a create method with axios. Exactly the same structure, but with DELETE and POST methods. It only fires the catch callback on POST.

Comment: Ok, seems to work now. Check my answer

Comment: In my case it was my axios interceptor that made sure the catch block was never called

Answer (score 0):

For your sweetalerts, change the key `icon` to `type`. Otherwise I think the success message shows by default. So the code should read

```
axios({
       url: '/api/contract/' + id,
       method: 'put',
       data: {
             name: name
       }
       }) .then((response) => {
          this.$emit('fetchAll');
          swal({
               title: "Success!",
               type: "success"
          });
       }) .catch(error => {
          this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
          swal({
             title: "Error",
             text: error.response.data.message,
             type: "error"
       });
});
```

Comment: With that I get the success message without an icon

Comment: Ahh, what version of sweetalert2 are you using? I can't see the `icon` option anywhere in the docs - https://sweetalert2.github.io

Comment: I use sweetalert 2.1.0 for my project. But the alert shouldn't be the problem, it is the wrong callback from axios.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem now, the callback parameter should be defined as Object. I don't know why it is a problem, but it is fixed now.

```
axios({
   url: '/api/contract/' + id,
   method: 'put',
   data: {
         name: name
   }
   }) .then(({data}) => { <-------instead of (response)
      this.$emit('fetchAll');
      swal({
           title: "Success!",
           icon: "success"
      });
   }) .catch(error => {
      this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
      swal({
         title: "Error",
         text: error.response.data.message,
         icon: "error"
   });
```

});

Comment: This literally cannot be the solution. There is zero difference functionally between this and your original code

Comment: @Phil It seemed weird to me, but it is the only change that works

Comment: I suspect you probably just fixed up some mismatched braces or something similar (and the code in your question wasn't an exact copy). If you used better indentation, you would probably see it better

Comment: The code is a copy and I really just changed the braces around the parameter. As soon as I delete them, it stops working.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really not buying it. `(response) => { ... }` is no different to `({data}) => { ... }` or even `() => { ... }` since you do not use `response` or `data`

Comment: I looked in SmartGit, the only changes in the commit are those braces, no change I forgot about. I can't understand it myself right now.